# Java 8 stream reduce Map

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have a LinkedHashMap which contains multiple entries. I'd like to reduce the multiple entries to a single one in the first step, and than map that to a single String.
For example:
I'm starting with a Map like this:

```
{"<a>"="</a>", "<b>"="</b>", "<c>"="</c>", "<d>"="</d>"}
```

And finally I want to get a String like this:

```
<a><b><c><d></d></c></b></a>
```

(In that case the String contains the keys in order, than the values in reverse order. But that doesn't really matter, I'd like an general solution)

I think I need map.entrySet().stream().reduce(), but I have no idea what to write in the reduce method, and how  to continue.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "reduce the multiple entries to a single one." A single one of what? A single entry? And what do you mean by a general solution?

Comment: I'd like to reduce multiple entries to a single entry with a Function. The reduce() method uses BinaryOperator. In my example, this BinaryOperator gets two Entries, concats the two keys, and "reverse concats" the two values. But I don't know how to implement it.
Also the reduce() needs an identity element

Comment: Is the existence of an intermediate reduced entry really a requirement? That contradicts the statement “I'd like an general solution”. E.g. you could simply use `String result = String.join("", map.keySet())+map.values().stream().reduce("", (a,b)->b+a);`. If you insist on a single `Stream` operation, you could use `String result = Stream.concat(map.keySet().stream(), map.values().stream().collect(ArrayDeque<String>::new, ArrayDeque::addFirst, (a,b) -> b.descendingIterator().forEachRemaining(a::addFirst)).stream()) .collect(Collectors.joining());` without constructing `Map.Entry` instances.

Comment: I didn't think about the String.join solution. The second solution is difficult for me, I'm just learning the stream API. But I like it a lot, so I hope I'll understand more and more of it.
No, the intermediate entry isn't required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're reducing entries by concatenating keys with keys and values with values, the identity you're looking for is an entry with empty strings for both key and value.

```
String reduceEntries(LinkedHashMap<String, String> map) {
    Entry<String, String> entry =
        map.entrySet()
           .stream()
           .reduce(
               new SimpleImmutableEntry<>("", ""),
               (left, right) ->
                   new SimpleImmutableEntry<>(
                       left.getKey() + right.getKey(),
                       right.getValue() + left.getValue()
                   )
           );
    return entry.getKey() + entry.getValue();
}
```

Java 9 adds a static method [`Map.entry(key, value)`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entry-K-V-) for creating immutable entries.

Comment: This is the functional solution I was thinking of. Could use some explanation though.

Comment: Thanks, that should do it. My main problem was that Entry can't be instantiated. The SimpleImmutableEntry should solve the problem.

Comment: It gives me "Incompatible parameter types in lambda expression"

Comment: The lambda parameter types are inferred just fine for me in jshell. What types did you specify?

Comment: My bad, I missed a diamond operator in my code, and it caused strange errors. I really hate that in Java. If you forget a single diamond operator, you will search the problems for hours. And all of this is for backwards compatibility with non-generic libraries.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example about how I would do it :

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

public class Main {

    static String result = "";

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("<a>", "</a>");
        map.put("<b>", "</b>");
        map.put("<c>", "</c>");
        map.put("<d>", "</d>");

        map.keySet().forEach(s -> result += s);
        map.values().forEach(s -> result += s);

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

note: you can reverse values() to get d first with ArrayUtils.reverse()

Comment: Yes, it's easy to do it that way, but I'm especially interested in the stream solution. Maybe not exactly reduce() is the appropriate, maybe it's Collectors.joining(), or Collectors.reducing(), but I'd like to make it in a single stream-related statement